# How to scope styles in angular?

Tags: angular

How to scope a style tag in angular?

Is there a way to scope a style tag in angular?

Following is an angular component template:

```
<textarea type="text" [formControl]="cssControl" (change)="onInputStyle()"></textarea>

<div #displayStyles>

//... here I append a dynamic component whose styles can be manipulated 
// using the above text area (list of class names of inside that component 
// will be given to the user to manipulate)

</div>
```

So I dynamically append a component to the div with ref `#displayStyles`

The idea here is to create a css editor.
The changes inside the textarea will be reflected inside the component which is appended to the div with ref `#displayStyles`

So to achieve that this is what I does:

```
@ViewChild('displayStyles') displayStylesRef
styleSheet
cssControl = new FormControl('')
ngOnInit() {
this.styleSheet = document.createElement('style')
this.renderer.appendChild(this.displayStylesRef.nativeElement, this.styleSheet)

this.cssControl.valueChanges.subscribe(change => this.styleSheet.innerHTML = change)

}
```

The above idea works fine.

**But the issue is that the user can manipulate the styles outside the scope of template ref  `#displayStyles`.**

Which means the user can manipulate styles of any element on the page (using the classname).

So I want a way to prevent that.

**Note** note that I don't wanna use `ngStyle` or `ngClass` as this cannot support css rules like `@media` `@keyframes` `:pseudo elements`. So the only way to include them is to use a `<style>` tag.

Or if it is possible to append the css to the styles of component decorator styles array then it is also welcomed.

Like this.

```
@Component({
styles:[...push rules in to this array]
})
```

Or if there is a way to inject styles to the div with ref  `#displayStyles` (scope the styles to this ref), then suggest that also.

**Remember** I wanna support css rulesets like  `@media` `@keyframes` `:pseudo elements` so cannot depend on angular way of styling using `ngStyle` or `ngClass`. This is not just a simple dynamic style change, Whatever changes that we can make using the regular css (like `@media` `@keyframes` `:pseudo elements`) I wanna achieve that here. Think it of like `codepen` or `stackblitz` in terms of css editor.

Also inline styling is not recommended since we have css rule sets getting as input from user... (ie. with class names and all ... media queries, pseudo elements, custom selectors like this `[class*="col-"]` etc...)

Like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}

h1   {color: blue;}
p    {color: red;}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Also I've tried to parse the css using regex and then inject those styles by query selecting class names. But that's really limited, cause sometimes pseudo selectors like `:hover` & custom regex css selectors used by the user ( `[class*="col-"]`) and all cannot be added dynamically using javascript. So the only easy way I think is a script tag.

**Any idea is welcomed. Please suggest something.**

Comment: did my answer help at all? @mex

Comment: No. I'm not sure you get my question>

Answer (score 0):

in the spirit of suggesting some things for you..

1. every component has it's own css scope.  so it is possible that you can just break up the css scopes by component?
2. it looks like some of these have been depreciated but there are some scope css tricks, here is the main article:

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-content